# Chrome WebDriver - C#.NET How to load existing chrome cookie/profile, so I can bypass the authentication

Tags: selenium, session, load, profile, chrome-options

I am having really difficult during development. Every time I run a Selenium test via VS.NET, the website I want to automate always ask for all security questions. It's very time-consuming. If I open the same webpage using Chrome, it has all the cookie stored. Is there a way to import my existing chrome cookie? So when I run or debug via VS.NET, it does not ask all security questions?

string driverpath = "C:\Users\shirl\source\repos\IronPythonApplication2\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.88.0.4324.9600\driver\win32\";

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.AddArgument("user-data-dir=C:\Users\shirl\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default");

driver = new ChromeDriver(driverpath, options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.google.com");

Thanks so much.